# Having troubles using R and XML to parse national weather service data

Tags: r, xml

I have been using the following script which worked well for many years but an update of the XML package in R I think rendered what I had to only partially work.

```
download.file("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.9733&lon=-121.6413&FcstType=digitalDWML","temp.xml") #This is for the lake surface
data1 <- xmlParse("temp.xml")

temp_path <- "//temperature[@type='hourly']/value"
precip_path <- "//hourly-qpf[@type='floating']/value"

df1 <- data.frame(
  latitude=data1[["number(//point/@latitude)"]],
  longitude=data1[["number(//point/@longitude)"]],
  hourly_temperature=as.integer(sapply(data1[temp_path], as, "integer"))
  hourly_precip=as.numeric(sapply(data1[precip_path],as,"double"))
)

df1$date1<- seq(Sys.time(), by="hour", length.out = length(df1$hourly_temperature))
```

The hourly temperature part parses correctly but the precipitation part does not parse correctly anymore. I have tried a number of different options but apparently I am bad with XML. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If you think the version of the xml package is at fault, why not install an older one?

Comment: Likely the data changed and not the package. Check xpaths still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't an issue using the xml2 package.

```
download.file("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.9733&lon=-121.6413&FcstType=digitalDWML","temp.xml") #This is for the lake surface

library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
data1 <- read_xml("temp.xml")

latitude <- data1 %>% xml_find_first(".//point") %>% xml_attr("latitude")
longitude<- data1 %>% xml_find_first(".//point") %>% xml_attr("longitude")

temperature <- data1 %>% xml_find_all(".//temperature[@type='hourly']/value") %>% xml_integer() 
precip <- data1 %>% xml_find_all(".//hourly-qpf[@type='floating']/value") %>% xml_double() 

start_time <-  data1 %>% xml_find_all(".//start-valid-time") %>% xml_text() %>% as.POSIXct("%FT%T", tz="Etc/GMT-7")
df1 <- data.frame(start_time, latitude, longitude, temperature, precip)
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented, there is no issue with `XML` package but the XML data. Precipitation data contains missing values at the end of its section where your attempted `sapply` + `as` + `"numeric"` iterative call errs out in type conversion.

```xml
   <value xsi:nil="true"/>
   <value xsi:nil="true"/>
   <value xsi:nil="true"/>
   <value xsi:nil="true"/>
</hourly-qpf>
```

Instead, consider using XML's `xpathSApply` + `xmlValue` to properly handle type conversion of original text content. (Also no need to `download.file` but use `readLines` on URL).

```r
library(XML)
url <- "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.9733&lon=-121.6413&FcstType=digitalDWML"

data1 <- xmlParse(readLines(url))

temp_path <- "//temperature[@type='hourly']/value"
precip_path <- "//hourly-qpf[@type='floating']/value"

df1 <- transform(
          data.frame(
              latitude=data1[["number(//point/@latitude)"]],
              longitude=data1[["number(//point/@longitude)"]],
              hourly_temperature=as.integer(xpathSApply(data1, temp_path, xmlValue)),
              hourly_precip= as.numeric(xpathSApply(data1, precip_path, xmlValue))
          ),
          date1 = seq(Sys.time(), by="hour", length.out = length(hourly_temperature))
       )
```

**Output**

```r
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 168 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ latitude          : num  48 48 48 48 48 ...
#  $ longitude         : num  -122 -122 -122 -122 -122 ...
#  $ hourly_temperature: int  26 28 30 32 32 34 35 35 35 35 ...
#  $ hourly_precip     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ date1             : POSIXct, format: "2021-04-11 11:15:00" "2021-04-11 12:15:00" "2021-04-11 13:15:00" "2021-04-11 14:15:00" ...

head(df1)
#   latitude longitude hourly_temperature hourly_precip               date1
# 1    47.98   -121.64                 26             0 2021-04-11 11:15:00
# 2    47.98   -121.64                 28             0 2021-04-11 12:15:00
# 3    47.98   -121.64                 30             0 2021-04-11 13:15:00
# 4    47.98   -121.64                 32             0 2021-04-11 14:15:00
# 5    47.98   -121.64                 32             0 2021-04-11 15:15:00
# 6    47.98   -121.64                 34             0 2021-04-11 16:15:00

tail(df1)
#     latitude longitude hourly_temperature hourly_precip               date1
# 163    47.98   -121.64                 39             0 2021-04-18 05:15:00
# 164    47.98   -121.64                 38             0 2021-04-18 06:15:00
# 165    47.98   -121.64                 38            NA 2021-04-18 07:15:00
# 166    47.98   -121.64                 39            NA 2021-04-18 08:15:00
# 167    47.98   -121.64                 41            NA 2021-04-18 09:15:00
# 168    47.98   -121.64                 43            NA 2021-04-18 10:15:00
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured that it was something with the way they changed the data as they have never had a 'no data' in the precip field but could not figure out how to parse it correctly. Thank you again!!!